# Sumif months > specified date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Dataframe

```
 name subscribe_date 1/2019 2/2019  3/2019  .......  1/2021 2/2021 3/2021
2 Andy   2020-10-01      50     30     20       .......    200    40      60
```

I would like to create a `post_subs_total` column that takes the sum of row 2 from the cells 1/2021 to 3/2021 for the months after the subscribe date.

In the example above, the result would be:

```
 name subscribe_date 1/2020 2/2020  3/2020  .......  1/2021 2/2021 3/2021 post_subs_total
2 Andy   2020-10-01      50     30     20       .......    200    40      60        300
```

The data has to stay in horizontal format, because I would like to know how much each customer spends after his subscribe date.

[image]

Comment: Is the date an actual date recognised by Excel?  e.g. 01/01/20 with a custom format of `mmm\_yy`?

Comment: You've made it hard for yourself with your headers. I would change them to a date (01/01/20) and format the date as you wish. Then sumif should work fairly well

Comment: the months are now in the format of m"/"yyyy, for instance "1/2019"

Comment: how should I best approach it with sumif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that the header row containing your dates are truly [Excel date values](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-dates-work-in-excel/). You can have them formatted to look exactly the same (e.g. "3/2019") by formatting those cells using the [custom date format](https://www.excel-university.com/custom-date-formats/) of "m/yyyy", or any other format you choose.

To generate the "post_subs_total" for the image of your worksheet, use this formula in Cell R2:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:Q2,C1:Q1,">="&B2)
```